# SiriKit fetch Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, sirikit

How can I send my app data into **siri** Intent class and how to handle the data in intent class. I followed the apple documentation for message intent and tested. My app didn't had even a single contact but **siri** always says "It's sent". If we want customize the logic, we need INPerson class type objects. I confused. If I had my application data in Intent class how can I change my contacts into INPerson class object.

Thanks in advance.